Simple OLS to measure correlation
I have two variables, X and Y, and I have good reason to believe that they are simultaneously determined.
$$Y = a_{1} + b_{1}X + u_{1}\tag{1}$$
$$X = a_{2} + b_{2}Y + u_{2}\tag{2}$$
My question is this: can I still study the relationship between the variables using simple OLS, as long as I stay clear from any causal statements?
I'm interested in making this type of statement: "a unit increase in X is associated with a change of b1 in the predicted value of Y". I don't want to imply anything about the direction of causality, I'm just interested in describing how the variables co-move. In this context, where I acknowledge the obvious endogeneity, is it still misleading to report coefficients?
Update: the data are purely cross-sectional

See How to Handle Many Times Series Simultaneously?.

Hi: Is the relation time series based ? You used $i$ rather than $t$ for subscripts so I don't think so, correct ? If the model was a time series model, then a VAR would be the way to go. It was invented exactly for the problem you have. If it's not time series based, then check out simultaneous equations estimation. ( systemfit in R may be helpful ? ).

I have taken the liberty to drop the subscripts and instead write
$$ Y = a + bX + u $$
$$ X = c + dY + v $$
Then, if we define $\beta = \frac{1}{1-bd} $
$$ Y = \underbrace{(a + bc)\frac{1}{1-bd}}_{\alpha\beta} + \underbrace{b\frac{1}{1-bd}v}_{b\beta v} + \underbrace{\frac{1}{1-bd}u}_{\beta u} $$
$$ X = \underbrace{(c + ad)\frac{1}{1-bd}}_{\gamma\beta}  + \underbrace{\frac{1}{1-bd}v}_{\beta v} + \underbrace{d\frac{1}{1-bd}u}_{d\beta u} $$
$$ Cov(X,Y) = \beta^2(b Var(v) + dVar(u)+(1+bd)Cov(u,v)) $$
$$ Var(X) = \beta^2(Var(v) + d^2Var(u) + dCov(u,v)) $$
$$ Var(Y) = \beta^2(b^2Var(v) + Var(u) + bCov(u,v)) $$
If we assume $Cov(u,v) = 0 $
$$ \frac{Cov(X,Y)}{Var(X)} =  b\frac{Var(v)}{Var(v) + d^2Var(u)} + d\frac{Var(u)}{Var(v) + d^2Var(u)}, $$
an OLS regression of $Y$ on $X$ will yield (in theory, as $n \to \infty$) a strange/improper variance-weighted average of the coefficients $b$ and $d$ (the weights are posistive but do not sum to 1). It is still technically correct to make a statement about the association between $Y$ and $X$ (at least in my opinion) but whether or not this information really is useful will depend on the context and what you know or can assume about $u$, $v$, and $d$.
One example where it is doubtful that you would be able to say anything of interest is if you were to regress the quantity (consumption) of a good on its price. This will yield  a variance-weighted average of how the demand and the supply of that good responds to price. Unless you knew that either demand or supply had remained relatively constant, the co-movements of quanity and price would mean little.
A counter example: in finance it is common to regress stock returns on market (index) returns by OLS. The coefficient from this regression clearly isn't causal (the market return is caused by individual stock returns, but any one stock has a negligible impact on the market). In this context, it has proved very useful to estimate the co-movements of stock returns and market returns to decompose the risk of investing in a stock into systematic risk and idiosyncratic risk.
If it is possible to frame the problem in terms of $X$ and $Y$ having a common, unobserved cause (confounding rather than simultaneity), then it would perhaps be easier to describe the association as a biased estimate of the causal effect of $X$ on $Y$
$$ Y = a + bX + \theta U + u $$
$$ X = c + \phi U + v $$
$$ \frac{Cov(X,Y)}{Var(X)} =  b + \theta\phi\frac{Var(U)}{Var(X)} $$

Thank you, this is an extremely helpful way of thinking about the problem. It does make intuitive sense that the coefficients are a little meaningless if we think that the variables simultaneously express the same phenomenon.

There have been some historical ways around this, particularly if you have ways to measure the directed effects across time. Suppose for example that we have measured a variable $X$ at two different years, $X_1$ and $X_2$, along with $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ for the same time period. If we treat the initial effects as variance we can attribute to the baseline measures, then we can construct something like a cross-lagged panel model (CLPM) like the below path diagram shows. Here we can to a limited degree assess reverse causality, as the directed paths, after controlling for baseline, are estimated both directions via cross-lagged paths ($X_1 \rightarrow Y_2$ and $Y_1 \rightarrow X_2$) while controlling for the initial estimates of each via autoregressive paths ($X_1 \rightarrow X_2$ and $Y_1 \rightarrow Y_2$).

Be advised however that this sort of model has become controversial over time. There are now alternatives, such as the random effects versions like random intercepts CLPMs (or RI-CLPMs in short), or the estimation of propensity scores with CLPMs. This video provides a good conceptual introduction to this topic.

Thank you for this. My data is purely cross-sectional, however

Hmm cross-sectional data already makes things difficult wrt to causality, and because you are trying to ascertain reverse causality, this makes things much more difficult. I'd be curious to see if others offer alternative suggestions given this is the case, but I can't think of any solutions to this issue off the top of my head with purely correlational data.
